# pass params to back screen and set in state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, cross-platform

I tried to pass param data from 2nd screen to 1st screen but not getting. i'm new  to react native. Searched on google also but due react native version change code not working properly.

here is 1st screen code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class viewA extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  state = { selected: 'hiii' };

  onSelect = (data) =>{
    this.setState(data)
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("viewB",{ onSelect: this.onSelect })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
        <Text>{this.state.selected}</Text>
        <Button title="Next" onPress={this.onPress} />
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

2nd screen code-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View,Alert } from "react-native";

export default class viewB extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
 goBack= ()=> {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
   this.props.navigation.state.params.onSelect({ 'selected':'hello'});
     }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
      <Button title="back" onPress={this.goBack} />
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props)}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

here is link of my react native expo link can edit code

https://snack.expo.io/@vikraant/param-to-back-page

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to pass? can you specify?

Comment: i want to pass 'hello' from 2nd screen to 1st screen @GauravRoy

Comment: why are you using drawernavigator? is it something required or should stackNavigator suffice the requirements? ill change the code accordingly

Comment: i don't know what to use for navigation. if i use stacknavigator it will resolve problem ? @GauravRoy

Comment: should i share a new expo snack where i show you how to pass data between 2 screens?

Comment: yes.Thanks @GauravRoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204321/discussion-between-gaurav-roy-and-vikraant-vishwakarma).

Comment: The problem is that you are using a DrawerNavigator. While switching between them, you are unmounting the previous screen. While you are in viewB, viewA will be unmounted, so the onSelect function don't exist anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how i pass data to another screen , please see the code and expo snack link below :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.navigation.getParam('itemId','No data passed')}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Text>
          itemId: {JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID'))}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          otherParam:{' '}
          {JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'default value'))}
        </Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.push('Home', {
              itemId: 'hello',
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}



const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Expo link : [expo - link](https://snack.expo.io/rJLE0sERB)

here HOmepage is first screen and details is the second screen .Im passing itemId from details to home back again and snding hello which im rendering in homescreen as `<Text>{this.props.navigation.getParam('itemId','No data passed')}</Text>`

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts.